# Find all worksheets with a specific named range

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am running a routine in MS Access manipulating MS Excel. 
I am making a consolidate report worksheet from all of the worksheets in the workbook.  Only some of the worksheet have a named range of "dockName". My routine is making an array with the dock names and the associated worksheet names. On the consolidated worksheet I am including a list of dock names and hyperlinks to their associated worksheets.

The code below works but it transverses the worksheets twice and I believe there is a better way to get the total number of worksheets with a named range of "dockName"

```
   ' cycle through each worksheet to find out if
   ' the worksheet has a named range of "dockName"
   ' if the named range is found increment irow

   For Each ws In wbWorking.Worksheets
        On Error Resume Next
            Set rngDock = ws.Range("dockName")
        On Error GoTo err_trap
        If Not rngDock Is Nothing Then
            irow = irow + 1
        End If
    Next ws

    If Not ws Is Nothing Then Set ws = Nothing

    ' redim an array with the appropriate number of rows
    icol = 1
    ReDim vDockSheetNames(irow, icol)
    irow = 0

    ' cycle through the worksheets and gather the 
    ' dockName and worksheet Name into vDockSheetNames array

    For Each ws In wbWorking.Worksheets
        On Error Resume Next
            Set rngDock = ws.Range("dockName")
        On Error GoTo err_trap
        If Not rngDock Is Nothing Then
            vDockSheetNames(irow, 0) = rngDock.Value2
            vDockSheetNames(irow, 1) = ws.name
            irow = irow + 1
        End If
    Next ws
```

Comment: You could loop through the names checking for dockName, use Redim to expand your array each time it's found and record the sheet and value.

Comment: @SJR I have read that it is very inefficient to redim an array several times. I don't know if the inefficiency of looping through the worksheets twice is equivalent to the redim inefficiency. Some of these workbooks could have hundreds of worksheets but only a fraction of them include information about specific docks.

Comment: I don't know either - perhaps worth a test. Another option would be to redim only once at the beginning based on the total number of named ranges in your file. Then you know you will have enough space (you will end up with 'empty' space in your array but that doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the suggestion of @SJR and supporting suggestion by @Andre I generated the following function which returns the count of a given named range in a given workbook.  The return value may be used to redim an array.  This functions and markedly faster than transversing the worksheet collect and testing for a named range.

```
Function getCountOfNamedRanges(ByRef wb As Excel.Workbook, ByVal rngName As String) As Integer
    ' return the number of times a given rngName appears in the given workbook
    Dim nm As Variant
    Dim nms As Names
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim iReturn As Integer

    Set nms = wb.Names
    For i = 1 To nms.Count
        If InStr(1, nms(i).Name, rngName) Then iReturn = iReturn + 1
    Next i
    countNameRanges = iReturn
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

It is no problem whatsoever to `ReDim` lots of times.

```
Sub TestRedim()

    Dim myAr() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim TimeStart As Single

    TimeStart = Timer()
    For i = 1 To 1000000
        ReDim Preserve myAr(1 To i)
        myAr(i) = "Sheet " & i
    Next i

    MsgBox "That took " & Format(Timer - TimeStart, "0.000") & " seconds.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

I had to crank up the number of loops to 1 Million to get the time over 1 second.

This takes my computer 1.1 seconds. With

```
    Dim myAr(1 To 1000000) As String
```

and without the `ReDim` line it's 0.4 seconds. Not really worth any further thoughts.

So as SJR wrote, `ReDim` in your first loop. Looping the `Worksheets` collection and checking for named ranges is more expensive by magnitudes.